# Как разобраться с правами на папку в linux?

Tags: linux

Хотел дать права на папку юзеру www-data потому что от его имени обычно работает php-apache и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Как можно посмотреть кому сейчас принадлежат права на папку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотреть можно командой:

```
ls -l
```

Поменять:

```
sudo chown -R www-data git
```

Comment: А можно как-то при команде ls -l видеть права не в виде -rw-r--r-- а цифрами тиа 644 ?

Comment: @fosh4455 `stat -c "%a %n" git`

Answer (score 2):

В коллекцию:

Вывод ркурсивно всех дирректорий в формате *имя* *права* *владелец* *группа*

```
~$ find ./ -type d -printf "%f %M %u %g\n"
```

Сменить владельца, если не www-user:

```
~# find ./ -type d ! -user "www-data" -exec chown "www-data" {} \;
```

Тоже рекурсивно, только используя **getfacl** для просмотра и **setfacl** для смены:

```
~$ find ./ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 getfacl

~# find ./ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 setfacl -m "u:www-data:rwx"
```

Ссылки

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)